# RVM switching to @global gemset instead of a specific one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

When I enter my rails dir on server RVM switch to

```
/home/capistrano/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/bin/bundle
```

although it should use `ruby-1.9.2-p290@mygemset/bin/bundle` as it works on my local machine. When I type `rvm use 1.9.2@mygemset` it works. Nginx server is also looking for gems in the @global gemset

my `.rvmrc` file:

```
environment_id="ruby-1.9.2-p290@mygemset"

if [[ -d "${rvm_path:-$HOME/.rvm}/environments" \
  && -s "${rvm_path:-$HOME/.rvm}/environments/$environment_id" ]]
then
  \. "${rvm_path:-$HOME/.rvm}/environments/$environment_id"

  if [[ -s "${rvm_path:-$HOME/.rvm}/hooks/after_use" ]]
  then
    . "${rvm_path:-$HOME/.rvm}/hooks/after_use"
  fi
else
  # If the environment file has not yet been created, use the RVM CLI to select.
  if ! rvm --create use  "$environment_id"
  then
    echo "Failed to create RVM environment '${environment_id}'."
    return 1
  fi
fi
```

Comment: Did you run the `rvm use 1.9.2@mygemset` as root?

Comment: no, under my user called 'capistrano' which is used just for deployment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RVM is going through rapid develpment so the syntax and functionality of commands sometimes vary. Anyway, I solved it with upgrading to stable RVM:

```
rvm get stable
```

which is now `rvm 1.14.1 (stable)`. Afterwards commands like `rvm 1.9.3-p194@mygemset --create`
 works perfectly.

Another thing I was missing is the new syntax for executing commands:

```
rvm @mygemset do bundle install
```

This will install all gems for given gemset and ruby specified in .rvmrc file

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood you but you could place an `.rvmc` file in your rails folder and put something like this in it.

`rvm use ruby-1.9.2@mygemset`

Whenever you cd into that directory rvm will use settings from the `.rvmc` file.

Comment: yes, I have there. it works perfectly on my local machnine, but not on a gentoo server